# FastAPI restart server over and over again whenever a new webhook is received when calling a def function

Tags: python, fastapi

I created a simple fastapi server to receive webhook, and whenever there is a webhook signal, it call the function printmessage() to print out the message "WEBHOOK RECEIVED". And the code appears to work, but whenever there is a new webhook, my server will restart again which is not what I intend to do and it seems that the problem comes from calling the function, it appears that whenever a function is called, it will run the main.py all over again ("PROGRAM LAUNCH..." is printed out when new webhooks received but it suppose only run once) instead running once only, but I just want the program to run the function print message()only instead running all the code all over again, how can I solve this issue?

```
#main.py
import time
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI

def printmessage():
    print("WEBHOOK RECEIVED") 

app = FastAPI()
print("PROGRAM LAUNCH...")
print("WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...")
@app.post("/webhook")
async def webhook(request : Request):     
    printmessage()
    return 'WEBHOOK RECEIVED'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [984] using statreload
WARNING:  The --reload flag should not be used in production on Windows.
PROGRAM LAUNCH...
WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...
INFO:     Started server process [13308]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49353 - "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
PROGRAM LAUNCH...
WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...
WEBHOOK RECEIVED
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49353 - "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
PROGRAM LAUNCH...
WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...
WEBHOOK RECEIVED
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49524 - "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
PROGRAM LAUNCH...
WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...
WEBHOOK RECEIVED
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49524 - "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
PROGRAM LAUNCH...
WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...
WEBHOOK RECEIVED
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49524 - "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
PROGRAM LAUNCH...
WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...
WEBHOOK RECEIVED
```

**INTENDED OUTPUT:**

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [24368] using statreload
WARNING:  The --reload flag should not be used in production on Windows.
PROGRAM LAUNCH...
WEBHOOK RECEIVE READY...
INFO:     Started server process [38368]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
WEBHOOK RECEIVED
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49675 - "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
WEBHOOK RECEIVED
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49675 - "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
WEBHOOK RECEIVED
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49675 - "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
WEBHOOK RECEIVED
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49675 - "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
WEBHOOK RECEIVED
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49675 - "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Comment: (1) What's your Uvicorn command line? (2) What happens if you also print `os.getpid()`, to see if you truly have multiple processes? (3) Does this happen without the reloader?

Comment: The expected behavior is what your code gives when running with just `uvicorn main:app --reload`, so there's something else going on here.

Comment: yes, my command is "uvicorn main:app --reload"

Answer (score 1):

my original command is "uvicorn main:app --reload" and after change to “uvicorn main:app” the issue solved, thanks AKX & MatsLindh